# Correct practices for collections

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, collections

I have been Googling for a while know and can't find a understandable definition of where to use the following collections and in which event they are more suitable:

- Lists
- List item
- IEnumerable
- Queue
- Arrays
- ArrayLists
- Indexing Properties

I am using C# and to give you a bit of a background on my education: at my limits I can create a picture manager that searches through a CSV file that contains picture paths and descriptions etc.

I am now looking into doing the MCSD cert and want a strong foundation of the differences here.

TIA

Martin

Comment: So basically you want a lecture from a data structures course?

Comment: Going from your experience to MCSD is going to take a _lot_ of study without any real-world experience. I'd suggest working in the field for a while before attempting that certification.

Comment: I passed the first year on my uni degree using c# did do data structures but my knowledge is a little rusty.

Maybe I should do this one first:

https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-gb/exam-98-361.aspx

Comment: On second thought I am working my way through the MCSD book and I have gotten through the first 105 pages fairly easily - what I was wondering about hasn't been covered in the book yet. Just need to get my head around it.

Comment: There is a chapter in a book called C# in Depth by Jon Skeet that discusses different types of collections (Appendix B, Generic collections in .NET). It's pretty detailed so I think you'll find everything you need in there.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

- List is a very generic kind of collection. You can use Lists if you have no special requirements.
- List items is not a list. It's one item in a list.
- IEnumerable ist not a Collection type. It's an interface which most collections implement. It basically defines the ability to iterate over the collection.
- Queue is as special kind of collection. You add thing at the back and take out of the front. Good for working list. First in - first out.
- Array are collection where you have to know the number of items in advance. They offer a fast access to a certain index position.
- ArrayList. I never use them. Kind of List.
- Indexing Properties is the ability to write code like the following. So access a certain position within a collection. `var item = list[4];`

But as a few comments mentioned: it's a long story very very short.

Comment: thanks everyone for your help also found this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y3x785f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

writing up my notes and combining with advice here :)

Answer (score 0):

First the interfaces, which build in each other:

- **`IEnumerable`**: provides a forward-only, way to enumerate items. No way to add or remove items. No way to know the count of items.No way to access items by random index. Items have no guaranteed order.
- **`ICollection : IEnumerable`**: adds the ability to know the count of items. Adds the ability to add/remove/clear the list. No way to access items by random index. Items have no guaranteed order.
- **`IList : ICollection`**: Adds the ability to access items by random index. Items have an order

This is the conceptual starting point you need:

> Enumerable < Collection < List

```
| Use             | IEnumerable | ICollection | IList |
|-----------------|-------------|-------------|-------|
| Enumerate       |         Yes |         Yes |   Yes |
| Count           |             |         Yes |   Yes |
| Add/Remove      |             |         Yes |   Yes |
| Clear           |             |         Yes |   Yes |
| Has order       |             |             |   Yes |
| Access by index |             |             |   Yes |
```

Your variables should generally use whichever *interface* best suits what you need.

If you just need a set of employees, and you don't need to alter the list, and don't care about the order:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employees = GetEmployees();
```

If you will need the ability to add/remove items, but you still don't care about the order:

```
ICollection<Awards> awards = GetStackoverflowAwards("Heffernan");
```

If you care about the order that items appear in:

```
IList<Answers> topAnswers = GetTopAnswers("Heffernan", 500);
```

## That's interface, the rest is implementation

Then there are the classes that **implement** those interfaces.

- List
- Array
- Dictionary

These are the concrete implementations that you have to instantiate to get the interfaces.

And i will stop typing here, because mean-spirited grumps will be closing the question shortly.